# How to delete a symbol and word pairing in Python word puzzle?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making this word puzzle where a user will be given a list of 10 encrypted words, from an external (.txt) file.

```
print "Welcome to Python Puzzle Model\n\n\n"
Words = open('words.txt','r')
words = Words.read()
print "Here are the list of words:\n"
print words
```

The words are as follows:

```
#+/084&"      
#3*#%#+  
8%203:  
,1$&  
!-*%  
.#7&33&
#*#71%    
&-&641'2  
#))85
9&330*
```

The user will have to substitute the symbols with words and try and substitute all symbols into puzzle.

I have developed the part which enters the pairings according to the user's choice:

Lets say, if '#' was to be replaced by 'B', the code would be:

```
print words.replace("#","B")
```

However, I need to develop the part that allows the user to delete a symbol letter pairing according to his choice. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have to memorize which characters we're already replaced... What's why we'll introduce `MAPPING` dict.

```
WORDS = get_words()
MAPPING = {}

def add_mapping(old_char, new_char):
    if old_char not in MAPPING:
        MAPPING[old_char] = new_char
        WORDS.replace(old_char, new_char)

def delete_mapping(old_char):
    try:
        new_char = MAPPING[old_char]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        WORDS.replace(new_char, old_char)
```